# Using clangd in files included verbatim

Tags: c++, neovim, clangd, nvim-lspconfig

I am using Neovim with [lsp-zero](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim/tree/v3.x) plugin. The following minimal example models a situation I came across in a large code base. The `#include` statement is used for snippets which repeat throughout the code base and every application has dozens of such files in the `main` function.

File `defs.h`:

```cpp
a = 1;
b = 2;
```

File `app.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a, b;
#include "defs.h"
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

LSP features work in `app.cpp` but not in `defs.h`. Is there a way to get some LSP functionality inside the included file? Ideally, I'd like it to correctly process compilation errors as if the file was included in `app.cpp` and be able to navigate to declarations of each variable.

### Notes

Running, `LspInfo` I noticed that that by default `clangd` runs in single file mode. I tried defining `.clangd` and `compile_commands.json`, but so far no success e.g. using `bear` I did

```bash
bear -- g++ a.cpp
```

But the LSP functionality was still absent from `defs.h`.

Comment: Do you have a compilation database that clangd can access?

Comment: I don't. Do you mean `compile_options.yaml`? In my own or smaller projects I was able to generate it with CMake and that was very robust, but when I write extensions/apps for this large code base, I don't have it. At the same time, LSP would be incredibly useful here as it would help with navigation/readability.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `compile_commands.yaml`, of course!

Comment: You need a compilation database. You should probably look into generating one of those first.

Comment: But even when I generate one with bear, I still don't see LSP in defs.h. It's clearly because defs.h is treated independently and clangd doesn't know it needs to be included in app.cpp.

Comment: Looking closer, what you're asking for is not going to happen. This is pre-processor abuse and should be removed entirely from your codebase. I don't even see this saving time. It makes the code very brittle, and obfuscates it. clangd doesn't treat *any* headers in the context of what files include them, because why would it?

Comment: Hmm... yes, I was prepared for a negative answer, but I thought I will try. It does look very odd. It's just hard to change a code base of 1M lines which does it so many times. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clangd does not currently support files which are not self-contained.

There is an open bug for this in the clangd issue tracker: https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/45

Answer (score -1):

I would like to make some suggestions to try in your case: there are ways to potentially achieve LSP functionality in included files like defs.h within your Neovim setup using lsp-zero:

Create a .clangd file: In your project's root directory, create a .clangd file with the following content:

```
{
"compile_commands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
}
```

Generate Compilation Database: Use a build system that can generate a compilation database (e.g., CMake with -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON).
Configure lsp-zero: In your Neovim configuration, add the compile_commands option to the clangd setup:

```
require('lspconfig').clangd.setup({
...
capabilities = require('lsp-zero').capabilities(),
cmd = { 'clangd', '--background-index' },
compile_commands = "build/compile_commands.json",
})
```

Maybe using alternative language server such as Bear, avaliable at (https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear). He is designed for multi-file projects and header parsing, potentially offering better support for your use case.

Another way could be by using Clangd Extensions like clangd-extensions for potentially improved header handling.

I hope it helps and feel free to ask more questions related to this case.

Comment: I'm not sure enough, but this smells AI-ish.

Comment: Did you try to generate the compilation database?

Comment: Running the CMAKE with  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON could be an suggestion to generate.

Comment: Sorry, I found your answer really difficult to read. I wasn't sure if it were AI or AI translator so sorry if it was genuine. I should have also phrase my question better. I had a compilation database - I've used bear too. Couldn't do CMake on my original project as it's too big for me to write all config files.